# Using the The Yahoo! JavaScript Compressor from Coldfusion 10

Tags: java, coldfusion

I use `createDynamicProxy` to instantiate a Coldfusion class implementing a Java `Interface` defined in a 3rd party jar file. I want to pass the class to the constructor of another class of the same jar: namely `com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.JavaScriptCompressor`.

It works quite well when the jar file yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar resides in a subdirectory, which is specified in the `THIS.javaSettings` `LoadPaths` member of the ColdFusion application. It does not work if `THIS.javaSettings` does not exist, even if the jar file is stored in the classpath set in the Coldfusion Administrator.

My Coldfusion code:

```
<cfset oErrRep = createObject("component","cfc.ErrorReporter")>
<cfset jErrRep = createDynamicProxy(oErrRep, ["org.mozilla.javascript.ErrorReporter"])>
<cffile action="read" variable="inputString" file="#GetDirectoryFromPath( getCurrentTemplatePath() )#examples/jquery-1.8.2.js">
<cfset joInput = createObject("java","java.io.StringReader").init(inputString)>
<cfset joOutput = createObject('java','java.io.StringWriter').init() />
<cfset compr = createobject( "java", "com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.JavaScriptCompressor" ).init( joInput, jErrRep )>
```

When `THIS.javaSettings` is missing from `Application.cfc` I receive the error:

> Error casting an object of type `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` cannot be
>   cast to `java.lang.Exception` to an incompatible type. This usually
>   indicates a programming error in Java, although it could also mean you
>   have tried to use a foreign object in a different way than it was
>   designed.

I wonder what does not work. Does the dynamicproxy have problems when the `javaSettings` are missing or the `createobject().init()` call?
Is it known to be possible to use an Interface from a jar file in the classpath?

I setup a [Github repository](https://github.com/bardware/yuicompress) with a working sample.
Copy the "/lib/yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar" to your ColdFusion server's classpath, comment the `THIS.javaSettings` line from `Application.cfc`, restart ColdFusion and see it fail.

Comment: So the goal here is to use the library *without* using dynamic class loading?  I cannot try it now, but just to confirm you are starting with a clean slate A) You then removed `THIS.javaSettings` from your Application.cfc  B) You removed all copies of the jar first. Then placed a copy in a **single** location within the CF class path. Example, WEB-INF/lib/yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar only C) Stopped and restarted the CF server. D) Ran the code and an error occurs

Comment: It seems to me the jar file has always to be in the WEB-INF/lib folder also

Comment: (Edit) No. There should only be a single copy of the jar in the class path. It can be placed anywhere, as long as that location is accessible to CF. Depending on where you place it, you may need to append the location to the class path first. However, some locations - like WEB-INF/lib are already part of the core class path. You can just copy a jar file into that directory and it will be automatically detected on restart. So using WEB-INF/lib is easier, but technically you can put jars anywhere.

Comment: Did you restart your CF instance after you placed the jar to the classpath?  That's the only way CF can pick it up.

Comment: When the jar file is accessible in the classpath the error is: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError cannot be cast to java.lang.Exception` When it's not accessible at all the error reads: `Class not found: com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.JavaScriptCompressor`. You are right, when the file is not in the class path but `THIS.javaSettings` is set correctly ist works.